# Source map is not genearted

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, source-maps, webpack-2

Full code: https://github.com/kenpeter/test_webpack_2

When I run `yarn dev`, then visit http://localhost:8080, no source map is generated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After adding sass loader in webpack.config.js. I am able to see source map. Strange......

Comment: why is that strange? shouldn't you expect to need that module given you're compiling sass?

Comment: When there is no sass involved. I am expecting source map for javascript to be generated.